# jenkins artifactory plugin: Target Repository is empty

Tags: jenkins, repository, target, artifactory

I am new to Jenkins aand Artifactory. I am using Artifactory 3.0.4 and Jenkins 1.535 and I try to create a free-style software project. Need to deploy the artifact into Artifactory repository by Jenkins. I use default user id and pwd for artifactory. Both Artifactory and Jenkins run as window service with default local system account.

I select Generic-Artifactory Integration, and the Artifactory server is set correctly. But Target Repository is empty.

Something is wrong with my settings.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4):

It was fetched by Artifactory Jenkins plugin directly in back-end ！！

Firstly, in system configuration, the artifactory server shall be put into url, and click the `Test Connection`, it shall return something like "Found Artifactory 3.0.3". If this doesn't work, you need check user/passwd and network connection. You can try in command line in that server

Command looks like

```
curl -uadmin:password http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/repositories?type=local
```

Secondly in the job, you need to save and open the configuration again, it will trigger the plugin to fetch the list again.

Comment: +1 Saving the job configuration, after selecting the server from the drop down, and reloading the job configuration page is what worked for me (this is very poor design IMO). When i did that, the three drop downs had pre-populated themselves correctly

Comment: Saving the job config, closing and re-opening did the trick for me too.

Answer (score 2):

My guess will be you didn't [define the patterns of artifacts to be deployed to Artifactory](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin#ArtifactoryPlugin-ConfiguringGeneric%28Freestyle%29Builds). For example, if you wish to upload all the zip files, produced by your build to `zips` directory, you should add something like `out/*.zip=>zips`. The help on the `Edit Published Artifacts` textfield is very informative.

Comment: Thank you very much, Barush. Target Repository has all the list of Local Repositories after defining the pattern of Published Artifacts.